# WSL Ubuntu 20.04 is giving errors when installing zathura and other programs

Tags: apt, bash, 20.04, dpkg, emacs

I am trying to install zathura, and this operation has worked fine for me on the Windows WSL2 Ubuntu-18.04. However, when I installed Ubuntu-20.04 in its stead, I keep getting errors like these which say that a very specific subset of packages are missing? Can someone explain if this is an error on the WSL2 side or the Ubuntu side and what I need to do to fix this? Otherwise I suppose I could just downgrade to 18.04.

I have also done `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and related operations before doing this, to no avail.

```
me:~$ sudo apt install zathura
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zathura is already the newest version (0.4.5-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.28.1) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/emacsen-common: 17: emacs: not found
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
 installed dictionaries-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell-en:
 aspell-en depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package aspell-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell:
 aspell depends on dictionaries-common (>> 0.40); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
 
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                        dpkg: error processing package aspell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hunspell-en-us:
 hunspell-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package hunspell-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libenchant-2-2:amd64:
 libenchant-2-2:amd64 depends on hunspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary | aspell-dictionary | ispell-dictionary; however:
  Package hunspell-en-us is not configured yet.
  Package hunspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package hunspell-en-us which provides hunspell-dictionary is not configured yet.
  Package myspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package aspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package aspell-en which provides aspell-dictionary is not configured yet.
  Package ispell-dictionNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                      ary is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package libenchant-2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libenchant1c2a:amd64:
 libenchant1c2a:amd64 depends on hunspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | aspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary | ispell-dictionary; however:
  Package hunspell-en-us is not configured yet.
  Package hunspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package hunspell-en-us which provides hunspell-dictionary is not configured yet.
  Package aspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package aspell-en which provides aspell-dictionary is not configured yet.
  Package myspell-dictionary is not installed.
  Package ispell-dictionary is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package libenchant1c2a:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of enchant-2:
 enchant-2 depends on libenchant-2-2 (>= 2.2.3); however:
  Package libenchant-2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package enchant-2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of enchant:
 enchant depends on libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0); however:
  Package libenchant1c2a:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package enchant (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libenchant-2-2 (>= 2.2.3); however:
  Package libenchant-2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64:
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.21.1); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.27.90); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.10.0); however:
  Package libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-online-accounts:
 gnome-online-accounts depends on libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (= 3.36.0-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gnome-online-accounts depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.12.0); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gnome-online-accounts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64:
 libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.15.1); however:
  Package libNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                           webkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of yelp:
 yelp depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.19.2); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package yelp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libyelp0:amd64:
 libyelp0:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.19.2); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package libyelp0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zenity:
 zenity depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.15.1); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                     package zenity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (= 2.28.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64 depends on gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 (= 2.28.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mutter:
 mutter depends on zenity; however:
  Package zenity is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package mutter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on mutter (>= 3.36.0); however:
  Package mutter is not confiNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                         gured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-session:
 ubuntu-session depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1~); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-docs:
 ubuntu-docs depends on yelp; however:
  Package yelp is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-docs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of evolution-data-server:
 evolution-data-server depends on libedataserverui-1.2-2 (= 3.36.4-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package evolution-data-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depends on gnome-shell | policykit-1-gnome | polkit-1-auth-agent; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.
  Package policykit-1-gnome is not installed.
  Package polkit-1-auth-agent is not installed.
  Package gnome-shell which provides polkit-1-auth-agent is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-user-docs:
 gnome-user-docs depends on ubuntu-docs (>= 18.04.1~); howevNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                          er:
  Package ubuntu-docs is not configured yet.
 gnome-user-docs depends on yelp (>= 3); however:
  Package yelp is not configured yet.
 
dpkg: error processing package gnome-user-docs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dictionaries-common
 aspell-en
 aspell
 hunspell-en-us
 libenchant-2-2:amd64
 libenchant1c2a:amd64
 enchant-2
 enchant
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64
 gnome-control-center
 gnome-online-accounts
 libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64
 yelp
 libyelp0:amd64
 zenity
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64
 mutter
 gnome-shell
 ubuntu-session
 gdm3
 ubuntu-docs
 evolution-data-server
 network-manager-gnome
 gnome-user-docs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: Could this have to do with Emacs? I installed it using this:

```
## install dependencies (got those from all over the net and from the snap)

sudo apt install -y autoconf automake autotools-dev bsd-mailx build-essential \
    diffstat gnutls-dev imagemagick libasound2-dev libc6-dev libdatrie-dev \
    libdbus-1-dev libgconf2-dev libgif-dev libgnutls28-dev libgpm-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev libice-dev libjpeg-dev liblockfile-dev liblqr-1-0 libm17n-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev libncurses5-dev libncurses-dev libotf-dev libpng-dev \
    librsvg2-dev libsm-dev libthai-dev libtiff5-dev libtiff-dev libtinfo-dev libtool \
    libx11-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev libxml2-dev libxmu-dev libxmuu-dev libxpm-dev \
    libxrandr-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev libxv-dev quilt sharutils texinfo xaw3dg \
    xaw3dg-dev xorg-dev xutils-dev zlib1g-dev libjansson-dev libxaw7-dev \
    libselinux1-dev libmagick++-dev libacl1-dev gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 \
    gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libenchant1c2a libglvnd-core-dev libicu-le-hb-dev \
    libidn2-0-dev libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev liboss4-salsa2 libsoup2.4-dev \
    libsystemd-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev \
    libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxshmfence-dev \
    x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev \
    x11proto-fixes-dev

## download and install

cd ~
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-27.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf emacs-27.1.tar.gz
cd emacs-27.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
rm ~/emacs-27.1.tar.gz
```

as presented in [this guide](https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl) and thought it would work and it seems to be more or less functioning well.